# KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON and custom KSP

Tags: kerberos, smartcard, credential-providers, one-time-password, local-security-authority

I'm implementing an OTP solution based on the Microsoft's whitepaper "[Strong Authentication with One-Time Passwords in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg637807(v=ws.10).aspx)".

The summary of the relevant part of that whitepaper is to essentially fake presence of a smart-card reader by implementing a custom key storage provider (KSP) for Windows CNG subsystem. However having followed the instructions as described, I cannot get my custom KSP to be used by the OS when required.

In my credential provider I am creating an authentication package with KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON and KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO structures. My custom KSP is referenced in KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO as required (it is also correctly registered, can be enumerated, and can be used with NCrypt APIs). However it is never loaded by the OS after ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization returns (not even DLL being loaded in memory) or during the call to LsaLogonUser() in my standalone test app.

The issue is identical to the one described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/01a2abf3-f1a2-49e4-bdfc-c5fb833dd830/lsalogonuser-kerbcertificatelogon-and-custom-cng-ksp?forum=windowssecurity) in MSDN forums (without any answers) and I came to the same conclusion that the issue is with the contents of KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO (example usage can be found [here](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/LsaSmartCardLogon.cpp)) - however due to next to no documentation and not a single example of this rare case, I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Have you ever got this resolved and got it doing would it should do? I have a similar problem.